# How to find the angle formed by a cevian in a right triangle given a condition?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> In a right triangle $\triangle ABC$, right at $B$, it is traced the
> height $BH$, in the triangle $BHC$, then is traced the interior cevian
> $HM$ in such a way that $MC = AB$. Find the measure of the angle
> $\angle MHC$ if it holds that $HC = BH + 2AH$.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\frac{53^{\circ}}{2}\\
2.&\frac{37^{\circ}}{2}\\
3.&53^{\circ}\\
4.&37^{\circ}\\
4.&30^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

In this particular problem. I'm stuck at the very beginning. **What's exactly the right drawing or interpretation for this?**. Can someone help me here?. Can this be solved using congruency?. Which among the identities of congruency of triangles would apply?.

**Please include a drawing in the answer** because I don't know which sort of appropiate drawing would be for this particular problem. Can it be solved using only euclidean geometry postulates?.

Typically I would put or place an effort in the solution of this problem, but in this particular subject I'm stuck at the very beginning because I don't know how to translate **what it is written in words into the problem** with accuracy so that the problem can be solved, thus I really need help.

If it helps, I found this problem in a puzzles book which goes by the name *Reason and logic* which is from 2000s and includes topics probably borrowed from Martin Gardner's 50's book and Moise Geometry's textbook from the 70's.

I really wish this can suffice to give information. So far, as I indicated in the problem my best guess is that the problem uses triangle congruency, but I don't know how to make the right sketch for making this to happen.

Upon on my progress I could spot that there are going to be formed two congruent triangles and if this condition is used then I believe the problem can be solved, hence what might be needed is to establish a relationship between the altitude from $M$ to $HC$ would allow the answer. Such approach is mentioned in the answer given below.

Therefore, since I'm not good in this topic, it would help me a lot if the answer would include a step by step solution so I can understand.

Comment: The answer is $26.57^\circ$. here is a [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWRbK.png) of the configuration (drawn to scale). Let's see whether you can figure out what the question is asking first.

Comment: Yes, the answer is $\arctan(1/2)$, which is approximately $(53/2)^\circ$, but certainly not that precisely. This is very bothersome. Mathematics texts should not give approximations as the correct answers without saying "close to" ...

Comment: @TedShifrin I had just posted an update on this question and given my interpretation and answer to this problem. Mind taking a look into it?. I have mixed feelings about approximations, sometimes I feel they are okay others, well not so much. But in the maths realm I do believe that it should specify what you had just mentioned.

Comment: @achillehui That's a nice diagram. I wonder what software had you used. If you have time. Could you check [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919846/whats-the-value-of-the-inverse-square-and-inverse-of-an-unknown-exponential)?

Comment: I use geogebra to generate the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

The interpretation of the problem is as follows:

Please see the diagram from below:

[image: Sketch of the solution]

This first diagram is a representation of what its intended to say in the problem.

The key part here is that $MC=AB$ this will be used later in the problem.

The following diagram is the solution and the way to solve it is by tracing a line as the altitude from $MP$. In order to take track of the congruency. Angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\omega$ as auxiliary are used.

[image: Sketch of the solution]

Therefore the angle can be obtained from the triangle $\triangle HPM$.

I noted that there's congruence of triangles: This is the part where its used the information given in the problem regarding $AB=MC$.

$\triangle PMC \cong \triangle AHB$ because of $A-S-A$.
For additional information and reference [this link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/triangles-congruent-finding.html) can explain the case.

This means $PC=BH$ and $AH=PM$

Here's where we use the second clue given in the problem where:

$HC=BH+2AH$

Since:

$HP = HC-PC$ and $PC=BH$

$HP = BH+2AH-BH = 2AH$

and since $PM=AH$ we're left with a right triangle whose sides are in a proportion of $1:2$.

This means that:

$\tan \omega = \frac{AH}{2AH}=\frac{1}{2}$

$\angle MHC = \frac{53^{\circ}}{2}$

Without resorting to that trigonometric function it can easily be inferred that the intended triangle corresponds to:

The ratio of:

$1-2-\sqrt{5}$

is none other than $\frac{53^{\circ}}{2}$.

Comment: +1 good answer, much clearer than what I could say.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

By the [chord-chord power theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point#Theorems)
with respect to the point $H$,
\begin{align}
|BH|^2&=|AH|\cdot|CH|
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Given that

\begin{align}
|CH|&=|BH|+2\cdot|AH|
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

we have a quadratic equation

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{|BH|}{|AH|}\right)^2 
&= \frac{|BH|}{|AH|}+2
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}

hence
\begin{align}
\frac{|BH|}{|AH|}
&=2=\tan\alpha
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\cos\alpha&=\tfrac{\sqrt5}5
,\quad
\sin\alpha =\tfrac{2\sqrt5}5
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Let $|OA|=|OC|=R=\tfrac12$.
Then

\begin{align}
c&=|AB|=|CM|=\cos\alpha=\tfrac{\sqrt5}5
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
|AH|=|MP|&=c\cos\alpha=\cos^2\alpha
=\tfrac15
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
|BH|=|CP|
&=|AH|\tan\alpha
=\tfrac25
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
|CH|&=\tfrac45
\tag{9}\label{9}
,\\
|HP|&=
|CH|-|CP|=\tfrac25
\tag{10}\label{10}
,\\
\tan x&=\frac{|MP|}{|HP|}
=\tfrac12
\tag{11}\label{11}
,\\
x&=\arctan \tfrac12
\approx 26.565^\circ
\tag{12}\label{12}
.
\end{align}